# How to simulate mouse move and mouse click on Mac using C or C++

Tags: c++, macos, mouseevent

I am trying to simulate mouse move and mouse click on Mac using C or C++.

But unfortunately I don't find any Libraries for the same.

I have seen windows.h (works only for Windows) and also swinput (works for linux)

Is there anything like that for Mac?

Answer (score 2):

`CGPostMouseEvent` has been deprecated in SnowLeopard. You can replace it with something like

```
CGEventRef mouseDownEv = CGEventCreateMouseEvent (NULL,kCGEventLeftMouseDown,pt,kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventPost (kCGHIDEventTap, mouseDownEv);

CGEventRef mouseUpEv = CGEventCreateMouseEvent (NULL,kCGEventLeftMouseUp,pt,kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventPost (kCGHIDEventTap, mouseUpEv );

CGEventRef CGEventCreateMouseEvent( 
    CGEventSourceRef source,        // The event source may be taken from another event, or may be NULL.
    CGEventType mouseType,          // `mouseType' should be one of the mouse event types. 
    CGPoint mouseCursorPosition,    // `mouseCursorPosition'  should be the position of the mouse cursor in global coordinates. 
    CGMouseButton mouseButton);     // `mouseButton' should be the button that's changing state; 
                                    // `mouseButton'  is ignored unless `mouseType' is one of 
                                    // `kCGEventOtherMouseDown', `kCGEventOtherMouseDragged', or `kCGEventOtherMouseUp'.
```

Mouse button 0 is the primary button on the mouse.
 Mouse button 1 is the secondary mouse button (right).
 Mouse button 2 is the center button, and the remaining buttons are in USB device order.

```
kCGEventLeftMouseDown
kCGEventLeftMouseUp
kCGEventRightMouseDown
kCGEventRightMouseUp
kCGEventMouseMoved
kCGEventLeftMouseDragged
kCGEventRightMouseDragged
```

are now at your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that you check how the Mac ports of VNC do it.